# Are these statements equivalent ones?

Tags: c++, division, bit-shift

Are these statements equivalent ones?

`value1 / pow(2, value2)` and  `value1 >> value2`

`value1 % value2`    and `value1 & ( value2 - 1)`        (value2 is some power of two)

I am curious in case when `value1` and `value2` can be 32 or 64 bit integers.

Comment: The first 2 are (if `^` is exponentiation). But one can cause overflow, the other cannot.

Comment: `2 ^ value2` is `2 xor value2`.

Comment: it depends on what type value1 and value2 are

Comment: For the first one: If we ignore for a moment that `pow` deals with floating-point numbers, and instead take a look at the definition of the right-shift operator for `E1 >> E2` in [expr.shift]/3: "If `E1` has an unsigned type or if `E1` has a signed type and a non-negative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of `E1/(2 ` *to the power of* `E2)` . If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."

Comment: For the second one: The size of an `int` is not specified (but must be greater than 16 bit). Let's assume `int` and `value2` both are 32 bit but `value1` is 64 bit, and both values are of unsigned types. Then `value2 - 1` will result in a 32 bit number (binary up to 32 ones) and will be promoted to a 64 bit number for the binary `&` with `value1`. Ex. (the `'` are just for better legibility) let `value1 = 0xFF00'0000'0000'0000, value2 = 0x1000'0000`, then `value2 - 1 == 0x0111'1111` but `value1 & 0x0111'1111 == 0`.

Comment: [DyP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) In your mentioned example value1 % value2 is also 0